# Application is missing a default group leaderboard (ItunesConnect error)

Tags: ios, error-handling, app-store-connect, missing-data, leaderboard

I am trying to update my game from 1.0 to 1.1 but get this error:

"Application is missing a default group leaderboard (ItunesConnect error)"

image:
[image]

I also can't save anything, when I try to i Get this error:

There was an error saving changes. Please try again later or contact App Store Developer Support.

I already contacted Apple Support but they didn't know what it was. they are investigating but it takes really long.

Did anyone else ever experienced this?

Comment: Getting this same error today.

Comment: @PWiggin figured out what it is yet?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.  I was hoping it was just an apple server issue.  I submitted a ticket, but have not heard a peep from customer support yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yi Yuans Answer is correct, unf. I am to noob to upvote it. That's exactly what Apple recommended to me in the same situation by pointing out the Game Center configuration manual.
I thought they are mad, as I did set the default Leaderboard before, and was unable to make any other configuration change stick. But I tried it anyway and it fixed the problem:

- Go to 'MyApps' page (The overview page).
- Click the three dots/ellipticals next to the Add App (+) symbol.
- Click 'Game Center Groups'.
- Pick the group in question.
- Click the empty space under "default leaderboard".
- Pick your default leaderboard.
- Click 'Done'.

Comment: What I cannot figure out is how to manage this if you do not have any Leaderboards to set as default.

Comment: Thank you!  I would have never figured this out.

Comment: @CoryTrese: Your GC data is part of a group. If one of the games in the group has a leaderboard, try setting the default leaderboard there?

Comment: Sorry, @Thomas you might be right, in general, but in this case you are incorrect. Apple has acknowledged a server bug.

Answer (score 0):

I have same error, now is OK, by steps:
1, iTunes Connect -> my App -> error App -> Click Game Center
2, default leaderboard, Click Blank place, see Screenshot.

sorry, I have no authority to post image.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zN5D.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/BmFhC.png

Answer (score 0):

We're having the same issue when trying to update the description of an app. We have Achievements for this app but intentionally did not create a leaderboard for it. Now we're getting the same error about missing a default leaderboard. I've sent the info to Apple, awaiting a response.

Answer (score 0):

I have been getting this error for days. Is there an official solution? What are the consequences of moving the leaderboards to a group?